# How do I enable the AccessFailedCount and Lockout functionality on ASP.net Identity 2.0?

Tags: asp.net, identity

I have try to for increment   AccessFailedCount using this code but it’s not working (In AspNetUsers table not increment AccessFailed Count).
=> In this Code My first reaction was that , When User Is Failed to Login so Increment the AccessFailed Count But Not Worked that Code So Please give me Suggestion for update code and any things.

```
                var manager = Context.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();

                // find user by username first
                var user = manager.FindByName(txtUserName.Text);

                if (user != null)
                {
                        var validCredentials = manager.Find(txtUserName.Text, txtPassword.Text);

                        // When a user is lockedout, this check is done to ensure that even if the credentials are valid
                        // the user can not login until the lockout duration has passed
                        if (manager.IsLockedOut(user.Id))
                        {
                         error message;
                        }

                        // if user is subject to lockouts and the credentials are invalid
                        // record the failure and check if user is lockedout and display message, otherwise,
                        // display the number of attempts remaining before lockout
                        else if (manager.GetLockoutEnabled(user.Id) && validCredentials == null && manager.SupportsUserLockout)
                        {
                            // Record the failure which also may cause the user to be locked out
                            manager.AccessFailed(user.Id);

                            if (manager.IsLockedOut(user.Id))
                            {
                                error message;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                int accessFailedCount = manager.GetAccessFailedCount(user.Id);

                            }

                        }
                        else
                        {

                                    IdentityHelper.SignIn(manager, user, RememberMe.Checked);

                                    // When token is verified correctly, clear the access failed count used for lockout
                                    manager.ResetAccessFailedCount(user.Id);
                                    Response.Redirect("/Home.aspx", false);

                        }

                  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to look into the SignInManager class in ASP.NET Identity framework 2.1.
See this blog post for more information [ASP.NET Identity 2.1.0-alpha1](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2014/06/05/asp-net-identity-2-1-0-alpha1.aspx)

The SignInManager simplifies the authentication, account lockout and two factor authentication verification process down to a single method call.

```
SignInStatus result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Username, model.Password, model.RememberMe, true);
```

You can then respond to the result of the sign in like this.

```
switch (result)
{
    case SignInStatus.Success:
        // Login success
    case SignInStatus.LockedOut:
        // Account locked out
    case SignInStatus.RequiresVerification:
        // Do two factor verification
    case SignInStatus.Failure:
    default:
        // Login failure
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to Login page
and change

```
wait _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(Input.Email, Input.Password, Input.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: false);
```

to

```
wait _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(Input.Email, Input.Password, Input.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: true);
```

locks out with default of 5 minutes,
Wait 5 minutes and you should be able to login in again.